# Why don't image anchor links load in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, git, firefox

I designed a static website (www.beppo.in) for my brand [beppo](http://www.beppo.in) and hosted it on Git.

See a comparison here of behaviour in Firefox and Chrome:

[image: Screenshot comparison]

The webpage opens properly in Chrome but in Firefox the image anchor links are hidden, as Firefox adds some garbage value to the `class` attribute. Even then, to my understanding about the multiple classes to an element, the object should render properly. But the elements are hidden for some reason.

The webpage might look a little tricky (I thought of making an impression with the design) and I have just completed 5% of the website, so kindly bear my amateur coding skill as I have not followed any coding convention since I'm experimenting with the design.

See the inspected result of the `img` element inside `div_snds` below; note the `class="changesrc kybykzzeojjrekictcig"`:

```
<div id="div_snds">
<span class="label">Find us on:</span>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/beppo.in" target="_blank" class="tooltip"><span class="small">facebook.com/beppo.in</span><img class="changesrc kybykzzeojjrekictcig" id="imgFb" src="images/fb.png" draggable="false" onmousedown="return false;" alt="FB" onmouseout="this.src='images/fb.png';" onmouseover="this.src='images/fb_link.png';"></a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/BeppoIndia" target="_blank" class="tooltip"><span class="small">twitter.com/BeppoIndia</span><img class="changesrc kybykzzeojjrekictcig" id="imgTwt" src="images/twitter.png" draggable="false" onmousedown="return false;" alt="TWT" onmouseout="this.src='images/twitter.png';" onmouseover="this.src='images/twitter_link.png';"></a>
<a href="https://www.google.com/+BeppoIndia" target="_blank" class="tooltip"><span class="small">google.com/+BeppoIndia</span><img class="changesrc kybykzzeojjrekictcig" id="imgGplus" src="images/gplus.png" alt="GPLUS" draggable="false" onmousedown="return false;" onmouseout="this.src='images/gplus.png';" onmouseover="this.src='images/gplus_link.png';"></a>
<a href="http://www.instagram.com/beppo.in" target="_blank" class="tooltip"><span class="small">instagram.com/beppo.in</span><img class="changesrc kybykzzeojjrekictcig" id="imgIns" src="images/instagram.png" draggable="false" onmousedown="return false;" alt="INSTA" onmouseout="this.src='images/instagram.png';" onmouseover="this.src='images/instagram_link.png';"></a>
<a href="http://www.beppoblog.wordpress.com" target="_blank" class="tooltip"><span class="small">beppoblog.wordpress.com</span><img class="changesrc" id="imgWord" src="images/wordpress.png" alt="WORDP" draggable="false" onmousedown="return false;" onmouseout="this.src='images/wordpress.png';" onmouseover="this.src='images/wordpress_link.png';"></a>
</div>
```

I'm puzzled if is it because of the Git as the host or my amateur coding skills or any other unexpected external issue?

Kindly help me out if anyone has come across similar issue and has successfully overcome it.

Comment: I am on Firefox and I can see exactly what you see in Chrome, maybe update your Firefox to the lastet version or clear the local storage so it might reload the styles etc?

Comment: May be, but I saw the same issue in one of my friend's PC as well. I can't ask all the website users to update their firefox right? Is there a reason why this occurs in firefox alone? Has it ever occurred to anybody else?

Comment: Thanks for your effort @AngelosChalaris :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysterious class `kybykzzeojjrekictcig` is being added by an ad blocking extension. Its name is randomly generated.

You can test this by reproducing the issue in Firefox, then disabling whatever ad blocking extension you were running and attempting to reproduce the issue again.

You can also use the dev tools in Firefox (or Chrome, if you ever see the same issue happening there) and finding the styles applied to the element due to the `kybykzzeojjrekictcig` or similarly randomly-named mystery class. You should see something like the following:

```
display: none !important;
visibility: hidden !important;
opacity: 0 !important;
background-position: 1px 1px;
```